# LaTeX in tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, mathjax, tag-wikis

LaTeX renders fine when you go to the tag-info page, for example, [abelian-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/abelian-groups/info). However, when you try to add the abelian-groups tag to your post it doesn't render in the pop-up.

This is messy. Is it a known problem? Is there some sort of fix other than using words as opposed to symbols. However,

"An abelian group is a group where all the elements commute."

is woefully inadequate! Using the definition of "commute" is much better than using the word!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/mathjax-in-tag-excerpts

Comment: While it is nice that this feature is now available, one should remember that there _is_ a limit to the number of characters in the tag-wiki-excerpt: `all the elements commute` is only 20 some odd, whereas `$a*b=b*a$ for every $a,b\in G$` pushes 30. Sometimes one has to play the trade-off carefully.

Comment: @WillieWong: True, but then you are trading off clarity for space. The excerpt is meant as a brief summary. I feel that it should be concise and clear, and if you have run out of space then make it even more concise and put the whole version in the main wiki!

Comment: But the pop-up shows the excerpt, which is what you are discussing. And my point is that sometimes concision of printed material does not correspond to concision of the "source string" with all the markups attached.

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of MathJax have made this fast and easy enough to do just in time before animating the popup.

It will be enabled in the next deploy.

Comment: Will [markup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/why-is-this-markdown-for-a-link-not-showing-properly) be displayed too, or is this change only about MathJax?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Just MathJax, markdown exclusion is by design.