# Enabling tag links in wiki excerpts?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wikis

I just suggested a change for the [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag wiki and excerpt on main, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/29956/6).

It was accepted, but I note that the `[tag:tag-name]` functionality does not work in the excerpt as it does on other places. Namely, it just displays in plain text.

I consider this to be <s>a bug</s> suboptimal, because at any place, the phrase "the tag 'logic'" is less useful than "the tag [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)".

Thoughts, references and solutions are all welcome.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to Martin Sleziak, it has been confirmed that this is "by design", see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151924) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6574#comment23443_6576).

Therefore this may now be considered a feature request. It is *not* a request to enable full MarkDown in excerpts; only the tag links.

Comment: Similar question, but about LaTeX, not MathJax: [LaTeX in tag wikis](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/latex-in-tag-wikis). From some post on meta.SO, for example [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/why-is-this-markdown-for-a-link-not-showing-properly/151926#151926), it seems that this is by design.

Comment: A bug is when something doesn't work as documented. A feature request is when something that you want is not available. This is a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: I hadn't found any "documentation" regarding what does and what doesn't work in tag excerpts. With the present information, it is indeed a feature request. Before, it was in the grey area between bug and request; I chose the wrong one this time. Perhaps next time I'll just add both tags.